Android Notification - A Card Displayed as notification
I am playing this game called Bible Puzzle Word and I came across this notification that I see every morning on my Android home screen even when I have killed the app last night and I am wondering how can I implement this can someone help
I have tried checking over the internet but couldn't find a relevant answer I think it uses some kind of foreground services and notification combination but I am still not sure


Probably draw over apps permission
